# IOS-UIView and UIScrollview

Tags: ios

Dear all,

i have `UIView` and `UIScrollView` inside `UIViewController`.
`UIView` and `UIScrollView` has same width, width equal 500,

I need `UIView` to scroll when I scroll the `UIScrollView`. How can I achieve this?

P.S: `UIView` is not a subview of `UIScrollView`

Thank you for answers!

Comment: Then why are you adding UIScrollview if it is not supposed to scroll the view?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly u need to add into ur viewControler a horizontalscroll view and then into that view and into that u add ur view and another scrollview.

I hope i understand ur question correctly.

Comment: thank you for quick anwser, @@ i don't understand things you say, i want horizontall scroll UIView when horizontal scroll uiscrollview, but uiview is not subview from uiscrollview ;)

Answer (score 0):

you need to make your UIView as the subview of UIScrollView then only you will be able to scroll the UIView when you scroll your scrollview.